# Octave ODE solver: issues with state & derivative vectors

Tags: octave, ode

I have the code to solve a problem of non-stationary heat transfer (no, this is not homework, but the code is taken from a textbook), which requires solving a set of ODEs with the Method of Lines, and goes as follows:

```
%Problem P6_08A
clear, clc, format short g, format compact
tspan = [0 1000.]; % Range for the independent variable 
y0 = [100.; 100.; 100.; 100.; 100.; 100.; 100.; 100.; 100.]; % Initial values for the dependent variables 
%- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
function dYfuncvecdt = ODEfun(Yfuncvec, t); 
Yfuncvec = [];
T2 = Yfuncvec(1); 
T3 = Yfuncvec(2); 
T4 = Yfuncvec(3); 
T5 = Yfuncvec(4); 
T6 = Yfuncvec(5); 
T7 = Yfuncvec(6);
T8 = Yfuncvec(7); 
T9 = Yfuncvec(8); 
T10 = Yfuncvec(9); 
alpha = .00002; 
deltax = .1;
T1 = 0; 
T11 = (4 * T10 - T9) / 3; 
dT2dt = alpha / (deltax ^ 2) * (T3 - (2 * T2) + T1); 
dT3dt = alpha / (deltax ^ 2) * (T4 - (2 * T3) + T2); 
dT4dt = alpha / (deltax ^ 2) * (T5 - (2 * T4) + T3); 
dT5dt = alpha / (deltax ^ 2) * (T6 - (2 * T5) + T4); 
dT6dt = alpha / (deltax ^ 2) * (T7 - (2 * T6) + T5); 
dT7dt = alpha / (deltax ^ 2) * (T8 - (2 * T7) + T6); 
dT8dt = alpha / (deltax ^ 2) * (T9 - (2 * T8) + T7); 
dT9dt = alpha / (deltax ^ 2) * (T10 - (2 * T9) + T8); 
dT10dt = alpha / (deltax ^ 2) * (T11 - (2 * T10) + T9); 
dYfuncvecdt = [dT2dt; dT3dt; dT4dt; dT5dt; dT6dt; dT7dt; dT8dt; dT9dt; dT10dt]; 
end
%
[y, t]=lsode(@ODEfun, y0,tspan);
disp([y0 ODEfun(tspan(1),y0)]);
disp(' Variable values at the initial point ');
disp([' t    = ' num2str(tspan(1))]);
disp('           y                  dy/dt         ');
for i=1:size(y,2)
    disp([' Solution for dependent variable y' int2str(i)]);
    disp(['              t                  y' int2str(i)]);
    disp([t y(:,i)]);
    plot(t,y(:,i));
    title([' Plot of dependent variable y' int2str(i)]);
    xlabel(' Independent variable (t)');
    ylabel([' Dependent variable y' int2str(i)]);
    pause
end
%EOF
```

Trying to run the code returns an error:

```
error: ODEfun: A(I): index out of bounds; value 1 out of bound 0
error: called from:
error:   ODEfun at line 8, column 4
error: lsode: evaluation of user-supplied function failed
error: lsode: inconsistent sizes for state and derivative vectors
error:   $path/lines01_diff_eq.m at line 33, column 5
```

It is the part `index out of bounds; value 1 out of bound 0` that I can't make sense of. Can somebody help?

Comment: Well, in the very first line of `ODEfun` you delete the contents of `Yfuncvec`.

Comment: I commented out the line `Yfuncvec = [];`, and there still is an error:

`error: ODEfun: A(I): index out of bounds; value 2 out of bound 1`
`error: called from:`
`error:   ODEfun at line 9, column 4`
`error: evaluating argument list element number 1`

Comment: Don’t have Octave so I can’t really check your code. Given error, I’d check that `y0` is the right length. Clear your workspace. Also, per the documentation, time is not the second output of `lsode`.

Comment: I tried that too, to no avail.

Comment: Adding a disp statement in ODEfun gives: Run starts at 10:35:33.54 Inside ODEfun Yfuncvec = 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 ... Inside ODEfun Yfuncvec = 97.704 99.973 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 Inside ODEfun error: ODEfun: A(I): index out of bounds; value 2 out of bound 1 error: called from: error: ODEfun at line 14, column 4 error: evaluating argument list element number 1 Could @LutzL help?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that that line:

```
disp([y0 ODEfun(tspan(1),y0)]);
```

Should instead become:

```
disp([y0 ODEfun(y0, tspan(1)]);
```

And also the lines:

```
disp([t y(:,i)]);
plot(t,y(:,i));
```

Should be modified to:

```
disp([tspan y(:,i)']);
plot(tspan, y(:,i)');
```

In order to make the code execute without errors.